# Why does terminal display None

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to make a neural network for recognizing three digit binary inputs. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np

#setting the data note that I skipped [0,1,1] for the test
x = np.array([[0,0,0],
             [0,0,1],
             [0,1,0],
             [1,0,0],
             [1,0,1],
             [1,1,0],
             [1,1,1]])
y = np.array([[0,1,2,4,5,6,7]]).T #note I also skipped 3 for testing

#setting the weight
w = np.random.randn()

#setting the unknown
un_x = np.array([[0,1,1]])

class nn:
    #defining back_prop
    def back_prop(input, weight):
        for i in range(1000000):
            output = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-(np.dot(input, weight))))
            weight += np.dot(input.T, (y - output) * output * (1 - output))
        w = weight
    #defining the sigmoid function
    def sigmoid(input, weight):
        1 / (1 + np.exp(-(np.dot(input, weight))))

#training
nn.back_prop(x, w)

#testing the neural network
print (nn.sigmoid(un_x, w))
```

I was disappointed when I ran the program in the terminal. The

```
print (nn.sigmoid(un_x, w))
```

line at the end was supposed to print a number close to 3, but I got a None response from the terminal. I might need a hidden layer for this program since this neural network might be too complicated. But until I get a response of why the terminal displays None, I'm not going to bother. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `sigmoid` doesn't have a `return` statement.

Comment: `back_prop` and `sigmoid` should be static methods, not instance methods, though `nn` doesn't need to be defined at all. The two methods could simply be defined as functions.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest putting a return statement. Sometimes the obvious will skip the mind.